# Dask array mean throws "setting an array element with a sequence" exception where pandas array mean works

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I have a pandas data frame that consist of a single column of numpy arrays. I can use the `numpy.mean` function to calculate the mean of the arrays.

```
import numpy
import pandas
f = pandas.DataFrame({"a":[numpy.array([1.0, 2.0]), numpy.array([3.0, 4.0])]})
numpy.mean(f["a"]) # returns array([2., 3.])
```

I want to do the same thing in Dask.

```
import dask.dataframe
import dask.array
g = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(f, npartitions=1)
dask.array.mean(g["a"], dtype="float64")
```

(You have to specify the `dtype`, otherwise you get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'` exception.)

The call to `dask.array.mean` returns the following, which looks correct.

```
dask.array<mean_agg-aggregate, shape=(), dtype=float64, chunksize=(), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

However, when I run `dask.array.mean(g["a"], dtype="float64").compute()` to get the final value I get a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` exception. The full stack is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 165, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 436, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 81, in get
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/optimization.py", line 982, in __call__
    return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 149, in get
    result = _execute_task(task, cache)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 29, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/reductions.py", line 539, in mean_chunk
    total = sum(x, dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in sum
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2229, in sum
    initial=initial, where=where)
  File "/Users/wmcneill/src.private/radius_limit/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 90, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is it possible to perform the equivalent Dask operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if Dask Dataframe handled this case, but it doesn't today.  It's not actually that surprising given the situation.

Your dataframe is a bit odd, in that elements of that dataframe are themselves Numpy arrays.

```
>>> f
            a
0  [1.0, 2.0]
1  [3.0, 4.0]
```

As a result, Pandas thinks that this is an object dtype dataframe

```
>>> f.dtypes                                                                                         
a    object
dtype: object
```

Because Dask Dataframe is lazy it doesn't actually keep track of all of the data at any given point, it only knows the dtypes, which in this case are pretty non-informative.  Dask Dataframe doesn't really know what do to with a mean computation on these complex elements.  It doesn't know if your elements are numpy arrays or strings, or custom Python objects, etc..

So it errs and you need to provide a data type explicitly.

The full solution to this problem is probably for Pandas to develop a much more complex dtype heirarchy, but that's probably unlikely near term.

Ideally Dask Dataframe would give a better error message here encouraging you to specify a dtype manually.  If you wanted to raise an issue, that would be welcome.

Comment: Is there any way I can make it work by specifying a data type? I played around with passing in things `dytpe="array"` to no avail.